# How to add tooltips in JFreechart

Tags: jfreechart, tooltip

I am  doing the following to generate the stackedAreaChart

```
CategoryItemRenderer renderer = new StackedAreaRenderer();
CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot();
plot.setDataset(dataset);
plot.setRenderer(renderer);
JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(plot);
```

how can I show the toop tips for the chart? Thanks.

Comment: I got it. I need to add renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());